# How to connect to laravel forge database via SSH tunnel using HeidiSQL

Tags: database, laravel, ssh, forge, heidisql

I'm trying to do the above. HeidiSQL has a load of settings and I have a load of possible values, but I'm not sure exactly what goes where. Here are the different places I can put values

[Settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSc6V.png)

[SSH screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeEU3.png)

And the values I have are as follows:

- The IP address of the database (v)
- The port the database uses (w)
- The database username and password (x)
- My ssh private key (y)
- The port I'm going to use on my computer (z)

I've tried many combinations, but generally get the response:

PLink exited unexpected. Command line was: C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe -ssh [ip address] -P [database port] -i [private key location] -N -L [my port]:[id address]:[database port]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I've now found the answer to this.

The information required was as follows and this is where it goes. Be really careful that you have *actually* put in all these values.

Settings:

- Hostname (A2) - the name of this database *It might be fine for this to be 127.0.0.1*
- User (A5) - Database username
- Password (A6) - Database password
- Port (A7) - The port the mySQL will be found at (e.g. 3306)

SSH:

- SSH Host (B2) + Port (B3) - Your database IP and port number (ie 23.5.4.3 22)
- Username (B4) - The username for your SSH login
- Plink timeout (B6) - You may need to increase this (to perhaps 15)
- Private key - Location of your private key file. Note that sometimes you might have a passphrase. If this is the case you'll probably have to use pageant which is downloaded with Putty
- Local port - Which port you want your computer to use for SSH tunnel. eg 3306

These are some articles I found useful.

[An article on similar topic](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=7767)

[if you are stuck you could try and ssh in without heidi](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel)

[Info about pageant](https://sourceforge.net/p/heidisql/tickets/2885/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem with Plink [has been solved](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/129), can you give it a chance again?